# Using a conditional in Wordpress header.php with Modern Tribe Events plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've built a website using the Modern Tribe events plug-in (not Pro version). I'd like to show a different menu when visitors are viewing a single event page where the event has a particular category.

I've tried:

```
if(has_term('music', 'tribe_events_cat' )) {
```

and

```
is_tax('tribe_events_cat', 'music' );
```

...but neither work.

`has_term('music', 'tribe_events_cat' )` does work if used in `mytheme/tribe-events/single-event.php` file.

So it seems the `tribe_events_cat` functionality is only available at this point.

Is there a way around this or a way to use `if(has_term('music', 'tribe_events_cat' )) {` earlier on in the code?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the third parameter of [has_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term), the `$post`. It would be something like

```
if( has_term( 'music', 'tribe_events_cat', get_queried_object_id() ) ) {
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for responding.

Answer (score 0):

try to below code

```
if ( is_taxonomy('tribe_events_cat') )
{
    if ( is_category( 'music' ) )
    {
        // add your code in header.php      
    }
}
```